# Degree of splitting field of $x^5-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the order of its Galois group?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

If I understand the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980455/proof-of-order-of-galois-group-equals-degree-of-extension) correctly, the order of the Galois group is equal to the degree of the extension. That said, I am fairly certain that the splitting field $E$ of $x^5-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is
$$E=\{a_0+a_1\omega+a_2\omega^2+a_3\omega^3+a_4\omega^4\}$$ where $\omega$ is a complex root of unity. $E$, as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, has dimension 5.

However, if I understand [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817047/how-can-i-show-that-the-galois-group-of-xp-1-is-abelian?rq=1) correctly, the Galois group for this polynomial is $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}^*$, which has order 4.

What is it that I'm missing? Am I misinterpreting or miscomputing the dimension of $E$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, or am I misinterpreting the post and the Galois group is in fact not the aforementioned group of units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial is reducible: $x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$. 
You do not need to add the element $1$ to the field (it is already there), only a root of the quaternary polynomial (which generates the rest of the roots). That is why the degree is $4$.

Answer (score 2):

While your $E$ is the right space, the set $\{1,\omega,\omega^2,\omega^3,\omega^4\}$ is not a basis for it, because that set isn't linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. We have the dependence relation $1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4$ (and nothing else), so any four of those suffice as a basis. As a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, $E$ has dimension $4$ - so it's not a surprise when the Galois group has order $4$.

Comment: Ah! I should've realized that the relation allowed us to generate the rationals using only $\mathbb{Q}$-linear sums of the powers of $\omega$! Thank you.

Comment: One additional question if you don't mind: is E going to be equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ or will it be something like $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)(\omega^2)$?

Comment: I suppose I am wondering how I'm supposed to symbolically represent $E$. My suspicion is that it's $E(\omega)(\omega^2)$ because elements will end up looking like $$\{f+f'\omega^2 \; | \; f,f'\in \mathbb{Q}(\omega)\}=\{a+b\omega + c \omega^2 +d\omega^3 \; | \; a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

Comment: Sorry, $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)(\omega^2)$

Comment: How you represent it depends on whether you're looking for a vector space basis or an algebraic generator. As a vector space, pick four of the roots to be a basis. If you're allowing multiplication, it's just $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$.

Comment: I ask because I also need to find a proper subfield of $E$ which is not $\mathbb{Q}$, which I think should be something like either $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)=\{a+b\omega\; | \; a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\omega^2)=\{a+b\omega^2 \; | \; a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Comment: A subfield strictly between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $E$? It won't be either of those. You need something that's actually the root of a rational quadratic, which won't be any of the roots of the original polynomial. One quick way - what's the intersection of $E$ and $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Would that be $\mathbb{Q}(cos(\frac{2\pi}{5}))$?

Comment: Yes, that does it. It can also be realized as $\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^4)$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.

Answer (score 0):

Order of Galois extension need not equal to degree of extension it is less than equal to degree of extension example is |Aut (Q(2^{1/3})/Q)| =1 but [ Q(2^{1/3}) : Q ] is 3 and equality hold when extension is splitting field of separable polynomial.