# Show that $\operatorname{Gal}((x^{8}-1)/(x-1))$ is abelian.

Tags: galois-theory, abelian-groups

Here ( [Prove that the Galois group of $x^n-1$ is abelian over the rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721864/prove-that-the-galois-group-of-xn-1-is-abelian-over-the-rationals) ) there is a proof that $\operatorname{Gal}(x^{n}-1)$ is abelian, but I'm having trouble connecting it to my situation. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: The splitting field is a *cyclotomic field*.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you explain that a little more? I'm not sure what it means for a field to be "cyclotomic"

Comment: Courtney, can you show that the splitting fields of $x^8-1$ and $(x^8-1)/(x-1)$ are equal? Hint: Only one of the zeros of $x^8-1$ is not forced to be included in the latter splitting field, which one?