# Abelian Galois group

Tags: galois-theory, abelian-groups, irreducible-polynomials

Exist any way to determinate easily that its Galois group
is abelian?
I'm studying now Abelian polynomials

Comment: Yes, for $f$ irreducible we have [this condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721864/prove-that-the-galois-group-of-xn-1-is-abelian-over-the-rationals?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: It is called Kummer theory.

Comment: Kummer theory only deals with cyclic extensions. Plus, depending on the base field the question has a plethora of different answers. For example, if the base field is finite the answer is "it's always abelian". I guess OP is taking the base field to be $\mathbb Q$. Then the answer is contained in the Kronecker-Weber theorem: the Galois group of $f$ is abelian if and only if the splitting field is contained in a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb Q$. For a general global field, the question is essentially CFT. I don't think there is any generic "easy" way to determine that.